# make text appear in div when hover over another div

Tags: html, css

I have an "empty" div that I'd like to fill with text when I hover over an element. The text should be different for each element we hover over.

Here's the [code](https://jsfiddle.net/anteo/gmqr1o0x/)

```css
.text-info{
  height: 50px;
  width: 200px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.economics{
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border: 2px solid black;
}
.economics:hover{
  background-color: grey
}
.workforce{
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border: 2px solid black;
}
.workforce:hover{
  background-color: grey
}

#economics, #workforce{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="text-info">
  <p id="economics">blabla</p>
  <p id="workforce">blablabla</p>
</div>
<div class="economics"></div>
<div class="workforce"></div>
```

I've tried with css only, to set p's to display: block when hovering over .economics or .workforce, with no result.

Any help will be much appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

With css you can only show elements on hover their parent element, like this:

```
.economics:hover #economics{
    display: block;
}
```

This will work if `#economics` is inside `.economics`.

In this case you can add absolute position to #economics, to be in the .text-info holder visually.

Answer (score 0):

```
<pre>
p {
    margin: 0px;
}
.economics {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    border: 2px solid black;
    display: table;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.economics p:hover {
    background-color: grey;
    display: table;
    height: calc(100% - 0em);
    width: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.workforce {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    border: 2px solid black;
    display: table;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.workforce p:hover {
    background-color: grey;
    display: table;
    height: calc(100% - 0em);
    width: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
</pre>
```

Comment: I just made it when hover on name then box will be in gray... you can also check it

Answer (score 0):

Just to cover other bases, you can use some simply jQuery to solve this using the .hover() method.

```
         <script type="text/javascript">
             $(".workforce").hover(function() {
                 $(".text-info").html("The workforce is amazing.");
             }, function() {
                 $(".text-info").html("");
             });

             $(".economics").hover(function() {
                 $(".text-info").html("I love the economy.");
             }, function() {
                $(".text-info").html("");
             });

         </script>
```

Put this at the bottom of your `<body>` and it should work.

Check: https://jsfiddle.net/tww259xe/

Answer (score 0):

If you really need a pure CSS solution, the only real option with the given markup would be the `~` general sibling selector.  The caveat with that is the the sibling must *follow* the main selector, so you would have to reorder your divs.  The CSS would look like so:

```
.workforce:hover ~ .text-info #workforce {
  display: block;
}
.economics:hover ~ .text-info #economics {
  display
}
```

See the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gmqr1o0x/11/)